# VarChar to NVarChar causing truncate error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, truncate

I am importing some data from a temporary table which has a column defined as `VARCHAR(150)`.  The destination tables column is defined as `NVARCHAR(200)`.  I'm using an `INSERT INTO` statement, but when I run the SQL statement commenting out this column the query runs correctly.  When I uncomment this line, I get:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Line 26
>
> String or binary data would be truncated.
>
> The statement has been terminated.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2)
SELECT column1
      ,column2
  FROM tmpTable
```

`col1` is defined as `NVARCHAR(200)` and `col2` is a `DateTime`.
`column1` is defined as `VARCHAR(150)` and `column2` is a `DateTime`.

When I comment out `column1` and `col1` the import statement runs fine.

Comment: Are you *sure* that the target table is at least as wide as the source table? What processing is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well this won't happen unless

1. a trigger is firing on the target table, and the error happens there
2. the INSERT does some processing that adds enough data to make it too wide

Also, what happens with this please? This can not fail unless there is some processing.

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2)
SELECT LEFT(column1, 200)
      ,column2
  FROM tmpTable
```

Comment: There is a trigger, but this doesn't cause the error.  Updated question with more detail.

Comment: @NeilKnight: is your SQL that simple? and can you add the trigger code please